# C# Delegates how to access both method creating delegate object?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# I am having bit confusion here. How do I access add & subtract method since there are two arguments ?

```
public delegate double PerformCalculation(double n1, double n2);

class DelegateTest 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PerformCalculation rv = new PerformCalculation(Add);
        rv += Subtract;

        double x = rv(10,20);
    }

    public double Add(double n1, double n2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Add ({0},{1})", n1, n2);
        return n1 + n2;
    }

    public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Subtract ({0},{1})", n1, n2);
        return n1 - n2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `pc(10.0, 20.0);` twice, and not calling `pc2` at all, hence the result.

Comment: @dotnetom This my other approach

Comment: It's a **delegate** - not a "deligate" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of arguments isn't relevant; both your functions match the same signature, (`double, double`), so you can create a delegate of either.

C# uses delegate chaining. The first two lines of `Main()` do the following:

1. (Create the `rv` variable and,) add the `Add` method to the delegate invocation list.
2. Add the `Subtract` method to the delegate invocation list.

When your method invokes, on the next line, it invokes the delegates in order. First it invokes `Add` (with the two arguments), then it invokes `Subtract` (with the same two arguments).

Since nothing is passed by reference, the result stored in `x` at the end of your experiment should be the result of the `Subtract` function.

If you'd like the results of both, you should do something more globally deterministic, like setting a class member instead of just storing a value that (ultimately) gets overwritten.

This is to say, what you're doing isn't *exactly* one of the intended uses of delegates in .NET. There's nothing *wrong* with it though.

Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish, other than testing the platform's ability to use delegates?